# Subs not appearing on Assign Macro list

Tags: excel, vba

I have code within a worksheet Private Sub PrintProject(). It has no arguments. I put a command button on that same worksheet and right click and Assign Macro. The macros available do not include PrintProject(). And strangely, it only includes macros from other worksheets, not the current one. How do I make my macro appear on that list?

Comment: Change `Private` to `Public`.

Comment: Changing to Public solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the linked duplicate mentions the case of `Private` (3rd bullet).